# Para que serve o campo Milestone no github?

Tags: github

Na edição de issues do github tem um campo chamado milestone. Gostaria de saber pra que serve e o que é aquela data e porcentagem que aparece do lado.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A funcionalidade *milestone* (*etapa* em Português) serve para agrupar *issues* e *pull requests* á volta de uma etapa.

Assim pode ter-se um registo de que coisas precisam de estar resolvidas para a etapa estar completa.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Nesse exemplo em cima, para a versão `1.6.0` de um dado código estar completa faltam 31 issues/pull requests. Desse modo é possivel organizar e seguir o estado do desenvolvimento.